# Calling a mustache argument inside one mustache argument

Tags: javascript, mustache

Im trying to do something like this but I can't find out how to do it :

I got a mustache arg called : `{{dropdown_}}` and another one which is called `{{number}}`

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
{{dropdown_{{number}}}}
```

For example : if `{{number}}` is 69, I want to show `{{dropdown_69}}`

Comment: mustache argument Inception...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make an anonymous function to perform the switch statement.  In the example below dropdown is an anonymous function and {{number}} is passed to dropdown.

Mustache Template:

```
{{#dropdown}}
   {{number}}
{{/dropdown}}
```

Javascript Object:

```
{ ...,
 dropdown : function(){ 
return function(text,render){
     var value = jQuery.trim(render(text));
     var test = Number(value);
         switch(test){
             case 69:
                 return render("{{dropdown_69}}");
                 break;
         }

        }
     },
... }
```